# How do I use WordPress alongside CFWheels?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

Anyone with a bit of experience with CFWheels will know how awesome it is, but also how fiddly it is with its placement in the web root / sub-folders etc.

I have a CFWheels website, that I would now like to place alongside a WordPress installation.

CFWheels placed in the web root (which is fine) and I would like WordPress to run in a sub-folder in that same web root named 'blog'. How can I do this without invoking CFWheels desire to find a controller or action called 'blog'?

I know that the 'miscellaneous' folder is a folder that I can place things that CFWheels will ignore, but putting the blog into this directory isn't really an option.

Any help or advice would be great.

**EDIT:** ***I just noticed that the miscellaneous folder has a blank Application.cfc file that stops CFWheels messing with it. I'm not around to test this right now, but will update later if it's possible to use this same technique on other folders I create. I may have answered my own question in record time.***

Thanks,
Mikey.

Comment: Yes, I believe that will work (your edit).  Please come back and post the answer so others finding this question can see it.

Comment: Yep, I will update it as soon as I know for sure.

Comment: Are you using URL rewriting? If so, Apache, IIS, or other?

Comment: Apache with URL rewriting. On Railo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing a blank Application.cfc file in the folder of choice, stops CFWheels getting involved with everything in it.

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress runs on PHP so CFWheels should never get involved in the process. If it does, simply change the DirectoryIndex (or IIS equivalent) to have index.php ahead of index.cfm for the Wordpress directory (or link to blog using full URL and not just the directory) and you should be fine.

Comment: The IIS equivalent would be the "Default Document" setting.